# Horizontal rules or not horizontal rules in NiceTabular

Tags: nicematrix, options, nicetabular

I am making a simple table with `NiceTabular`, one of its columns must occupy 6 rows, specifically of the second column. The problem is with the rules (is it possible?), and depend of options using the command `\NiceMatrixOptions{rules/color=black, hvlines}`

For example, the two possibilities were:

```
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c}
        \large{\textbf{Temáticas}} & \large{Estrategias de enseñanza} & \large{Competencias promotoras}\\\toprule
        \parbox[l]{5cm}{Conocimiento y razonamiento. \textbf{blablabla}} & \Block[b]{6-1}{estrat} & otra\\\midrule
        \parbox[l]{5cm}{Surgimientos de la ciencia moderna. \textbf{blablabla}} & & \\\hline
        \parbox[l]{5cm}{Sucesión de teorías. \textbf{blablabla}} & & \\
        \parbox[l]{5cm}{Articulación entre teorías. \textbf{blablabla}} & & \\
        \parbox[l]{5cm}{Ciencias formales y ciencias fácticas. \textbf{blablabla}} & & \\
        \parbox[l]{5cm}{Ciencias sociales. \textbf{blablabla}} & & \\\bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
```

without options, and

```
\NiceMatrixOptions{rules/color=black, hvlines}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c}
    \large{\textbf{Temáticas}} & \large{Estrategias de enseñanza} & \large{Competencias promotoras}\\\toprule
    \parbox[l]{5cm}{Conocimiento y razonamiento. \textbf{blablabla}} & \Block[b]{6-1}{estrat} & otra\\\midrule
    \parbox[l]{5cm}{Surgimientos de la ciencia moderna. \textbf{blablabla}} & & \\\hline
    \parbox[l]{5cm}{Sucesión de teorías. \textbf{blablabla}} & & \\
    \parbox[l]{5cm}{Articulación entre teorías. \textbf{blablabla}} & & \\
    \parbox[l]{5cm}{Ciencias formales y ciencias fácticas. \textbf{blablabla}} & & \\
    \parbox[l]{5cm}{Ciencias sociales. \textbf{blablabla}} & & \\\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
```

with options.

The difference is:

[image]

Notice the horizontal lines in the last table, for the first and third columns; but not in the first table. However for the second column, in the last table, is how I want if I use `NiceMatrixOptions`. This is my doubt. Why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `NiceTabular`, but there's something seriously wrong with the vertical line spacing.  I'd be more concerned about that than about the drawn lines.

Comment: From code fragments is not easy to see, what is cause of your problem. You should provide MWE (Minimal working example), a small but complete document, which we can test as it is. BTW, your code is quite unusual and showed result of it is typographically very poor.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not very familiar with `nicematrix` package but I'm very sure that using it you can write your table without use of `parbox`es. For first column you only need to prescribe adequate type of column (for example `X`) which enable automatic breaking of longer text into several lines.

Using `nicematrix` package for writing of tables, you should be aware, that table get final form after several compilation.

With `tabularray` package, code for your table is simple and gives far nicer result. Assuming, that second image show, what you after, the code, which generate similar structured table, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = 0.8pt, hline{2} = 0.4pt, hline{3-Y} = 0.25pt,
             vlines,
             colspec = {Q[wd=42mm, cmd=\RaggedRight, m] c c},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, cmd=\Centering},
             }
Temáticas   &   Estrategias de enseñanza    
                &   Competencias promotoras    \\
Conocimiento  razonamiento. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &   otra                        \\   %
Surgimientos de la ciencia moderna. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
Sucesión de teorías. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   \SetCell[r=4]{f} estat
                &                               \\
Articulación entre teorías. \textbf{blablabla} 
            &   &                               \\
Ciencias formales y ciencias fácticas. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
Ciencias sociales. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For reproduce above result with `nicematrix` package, you should consult package documentation. I do this and I would write table using it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\NiceMatrixOptions{hvlines}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\RaggedRight}p{42mm} c c}
Temáticas   &   Estrategias de enseñanza    
                &   Competencias promotoras    \\
Conocimiento  razonamiento. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &   otra                        \\   %
Surgimientos de la ciencia moderna. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
Sucesión de teorías. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   \Block[b]{4-1}{estrat}
                &                               \\
Articulación entre teorías. \textbf{blablabla} 
            &   &                               \\
Ciencias formales y ciencias fácticas. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
Ciencias sociales. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

After several compilations the table based on `nicematrix is:

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

**Addendum:**
If I consider image showed in your answer, then possible solution with use `tblr` of `tabularray` package can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                varwidth}   % that lists work

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = 0.8pt, hline{2} = 0.4pt, hline{3-Y} = 0.25pt,
             vlines,
             colspec = {Q[wd=42mm, cmd=\RaggedRight] X[c] Q[c, wd=0.25\linewidth]},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, cmd=\Centering, m},
             stretch=-1,%<--- remove extra space above and below lists
                        % with nosep option; doc p.51 tabularray
             measure=vbox,  % for listrs
             }
Temáticas   &   Estrategias de enseñanza
                &   Competencias promotoras    \\
Conocimiento  razonamiento. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   \SetCell[r=6]{l, h}
                \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=*]
            \item   bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla
            \item   bla, bla
            \item   bla, bla
            \item   bla, bla
            \item   bla, bla
                \end{itemize}
                &   other                       \\   %
Surgimientos de la ciencia moderna. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
Sucesión de teorías. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
Articulación entre teorías. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
Ciencias formales y ciencias fácticas. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
Ciencias sociales. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case, that you persist to use of `nicematrix` package for writing of table, the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs, 
            varwidth}   % needed for lists in table
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\NiceMatrixOptions{hvlines}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\RaggedRight}p{42mm} >{\Centering}X c}
Temáticas   &   Estrategias de enseñanza
                &   Competencias promotoras    \\
Conocimiento  razonamiento. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   \Block[t]{6-1}{
                \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=*]    % you may liked to omit "nosep" option
            \item   bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla
            \item   bla, bla
            \item   bla, bla
            \item   bla, bla
            \item   bla, bla
                \end{itemize}   
                                }
                &   other                      \\   %
Surgimientos de la ciencia moderna. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
Sucesión de teorías. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
Articulación entre teorías. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
Ciencias formales y ciencias fácticas. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
Ciencias sociales. \textbf{blablabla}
            &   &                               \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Result of three compilation is almost the same as before:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After think a bit time, I remembered the `\cline` command, that I used in `tabular`.
I added at the end of line, \cline{1}\cline{3} and solved my question.

Regards,
Darío

**EDIT**
This is the  MWE one that worked for me:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \toprule
        \large{\textbf{Contenidos}} & \textbf{\large{Estrategias de enseñanza}} & \parbox{.25\textwidth}{\textbf{\large{Competencias esperadas}}} \\\toprule
        \parbox[l]{7cm}{Conocimiento y razonamiento.} & \Block[T,l]{6-1}{\parbox[l]{.25\textwidth}{\begin{itemize}
            \item bla
            \item ble
            \item bli
            \item blo
        \end{itemize}}} & other\\\cline{1}\cline{3}
        \parbox[l]{7cm}{Surgimientos de la ciencia moderna.} & & \\\cline{1}\cline{3}
        \parbox[l]{7cm}{Sucesión de teorías.} & & \\\cline{1}\cline{3}
        \parbox[l]{7cm}{Articulación entre teorías.} & & \\\cline{1}\cline{3}
        \parbox[l]{7cm}{Ciencias formales y ciencias fácticas.} & & \\\cline{1}\cline{3}
        \parbox[l]{7cm}{Ciencias sociales.} & & \\\bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I use `\parbox` because it allows me to insert environments like `itemize`. This is a simple example relative to my doubt, after was updated aesteticly, but works for me.

Thanks for your response, I did not know how worked `ragged2e` package and it is fine. One observation, is `\RaggedRight` with second R capital letter, because it gave me an error.

Regards,
Darío

Comment: You should provide MWE, that we can test your solution. As answer is now, it is not clear and at least me doubt that it works.

Comment: Your MWE not generate showed table. BTW, in the first columns you haven't any list, Your question is now even more unclear what is your problem

Comment: AFAIK `\parbox` does not know an option `l`, but only `t` (top), `c` (centered) and `b` (bottom). Maybe you've mixed this with `\makebox`. So in the example all `\parbox`-es are with the default `c` placement (same as without `[l]`).

Comment: Using a `\parbox` because of lists is not needed and using the same `\parbox` for every entry makes no sense. There are column types, that allow paragraphs like `p` even in the native LaTeX tabulars. `nicematrix` extends this by several more types like `X` or `V`. AFAIK blocks also support paragraph contents (correct me, if I'm wrong, I've never used the package).

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you, in my computer and also overleaf it work. The problem was that the horizontal lines were crossed inside the `\Block` command, when it included a `\hline` or `\midrule`. This was saved with the `\cline{1}\cline{3}`. **Link to code (it working)** [link](https://www.overleaf.com/6939256998bknzvmtgjtrx)